# Creating and returning object from function: can this avoid garbage collection?

Tags: javascript, object, scope, garbage-collection, return-by-reference

If I have a function that creates an object, do some stuff and than returns it. If it's true that objects are passed by reference, does this mean that the function that creates the object (or the function's scope chain) will not be available for garbage collection?

Example code:

```
function convertArrayToObj(array){
   var newObj = {};
   array.forEach(function(item, index){
      newObj[index] = item;
   });
   return newObj;
}
```

I hope I made my doubt clear

Comment: No, the scope will be available for garbaging, there's no reference kept to it after the end of the function execution. The object is independent from its creation scope. You might be confused with closures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It (the execution context) will be eligible for garbage collection.

(The function object itself will be kept alive of whoever called it to begin with, until that object dies - but it will not be kept alive by the returned 'newObj'.)

Just because a reference to the object is stored in a local variable does not mean that the object has got a reference back to its creator.

Comment: Thanks! So a function returning an object will be garbage collected, but a function returning a function returning an object (created inside the 'outer' function scope) will not (because it's a closure)? Am i correct?

Comment: There are two objects involved in "a function". The function object itself, and the execution context created when you invoke that function. A function object keeps a reference to the execution context in which is was created, so if you "return a function", you will return an object which has got a reference to the execution context in which is was created - and the parent context will be kept alive as long as the returned function object is alive. You can think of the execution context as call stack frames, but which are stored on the heap and hence not destroyed on return.